# Why does g++ compiled file end with a % sign?

Tags: c++, macos, terminal

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello";
}
```

I compiled it using g++ Hello.cpp
I received the following output when I ran the compiled a.out file using ./a.out

Why do I keep getting a % sign at the end of the output?

```
./a.out
Hello%
```

Comment: This is likely what your terminal is rendering the null-terminator character as. You can easily test this.

Comment: Is your terminal prompt (`${PS1}` or similar) set to `% `? Have you tried `std::cout << "Hello\n";`

Comment: In the C shell, the prompt ends with a percentage sign (%). can you tell the output of `echo $SHELL`

Comment: Becuse you didn't end your output with a newline. Nothing to do with C++, it's just the way your OS works.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! all of you really helped! I'm just really new to c++

Answer (score 1):

The `%` you see there might actually be your shell prompt, and not part of your program output. You're not writing a new line after your output, so the shell prompt appears at the very end of the output of the last command.

Possible solutions:

- Append a newline to the end of the output with + "`\n`".
- Add a `std::endl` to the end of your output.